# How to compute fmod in C#?

Tags: c#, math

For given floating point numbers `x` and `a`, I would like to compute `r` (and `n`) such that `x = a*n + r` . In C/C++ this function is called `fmod`. However I do not see a convenient function in .NET. Math.DivRem is only for integers ...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I think you can just use `%` for floats as well. `r = x % a`

"[Arithmetic operators (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators)":

> All numeric types have predefined
> modulus operators.

Answer (score 6):

I think you are looking for [System.Math.IeeeRemainder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.ieeeremainder.aspx)

Comment: I believe this is equivalent to `remainder` which is not the same as `fmod`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/remainder